# Use a character vector in the `by` argument

Tags: r, data.table, data-manipulation

Within the `data.table` package in R, is there a way in order to use a character vector to be assigned within the `by` argument of the calculation?

Here is an example of what would be the desired output from this using mtcars:

```
 mtcars <- data.table(mtcars)
 ColSelect <- 'cyl' # One Column Option
 mtcars[,.( AveMpg = mean(mpg)), by = .(ColSelect)] # Doesn't work

 # Desired Output 
    cyl   AveMpg
 1:   6 19.74286
 2:   4 26.66364
 3:   8 15.10000
```

I know that this is possible to use assigning column names in `j`  by enclosing the vector around brackets.

```
 ColSelect <- 'AveMpg' # Column to be assigned for average mpg value
 mtcars[,(ColSelect):= mean(mpg), by = .(cyl)]
 head(mtcars)

    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb   AveMpg
1: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 19.74286
2: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 19.74286
3: 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 26.66364
4: 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 19.74286
5: 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 15.10000
6: 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 19.74286
```

Is there a suggestion as to what to put in the `by` argument in order to achieve this?

Comment: Use `c` i.e. `mtcars[,.( AveMpg = mean(mpg)), by = c(ColSelect)] `

Answer (score 2):

From `?data.table` in the `by` section it says that `by` accepts:

> - a single character string containing comma separated column names    (where spaces are significant since column names may contain spaces
>     even at the start or end): e.g., DT[, sum(a), by="x,y,z"]
> - a character    vector of column names: e.g., DT[, sum(a), by=c("x",    "y")]

So yes, you can use the answer in @cccmir's response. You can also use `c()` as @akrun mentioned, but that seems slightly extraneous unless you want multiple columns.

The reason you cannot use `.()` syntax is that in `data.table` `.()` is an alias for `list()`. And according to the same help for `by` the `list()` syntax requires an expression of column names - not a character string.

Going off the examples in the `by` help if you wanted to use multiple variables and pass the names as characters you could do:

1. `mtcars[,.( AveMpg = mean(mpg)), by = "cyl,am"]`
2. `mtcars[,.( AveMpg = mean(mpg)), by = c("cyl","am")]`

Comment: Maybe "highly extraneous" to use `c()` but also mentioned/suggested in some warnings like `'by' appears to evaluate to column names but isn't c() or key(). Use by=list(...) if you can. Otherwise, by=eval",deparse(bysub)," should work. This is for efficiency so data.table can detect which columns are needed.`

Answer (score 1):

try to use it like this

```
mtcars <- data.table(mtcars)
ColSelect <- 'cyl' # One Column Option
mtcars[, AveMpg := mean(mpg), by = ColSelect] # Should work
```

Comment: Thanks! Thought it would be something simple. It is actually quicker using this method than having c(ColSelect) as well.